# how to set http cookie in axios interceptor?

Tags: http, cookies, vue.js, axios

I am wondering how to set up axios interceptor for http cookies.

I use axios in vue SPA, back-end is on laravel, API sets http cookie, but now I need to send it back for some requests.

Actually I have auth token and refresh token, auth token is in local storage (it's short lived), application flow is next: On every request I set auth token in request header, laravel API checks if auth token is valid and if it is request returns data, but if auth token is invalid, I have to make new request with refreshtoken which is in http cookie, I know I can't acces it via javascript so, what should I do? How can I make this work?

Also tricky part here is I don't want to set refresh token on every request, only when auth token needs to be regenerate.

If i misunderstood something, please don't hesitate to put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this should get you going in the right direction:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  if (response.data.token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
  }
});
```

Comment: Yea I know that, my auth token in localStorage and I can set it like that, but I am confused about refresh token which is in http cookie